# How do I filter by file type on Sourcegraph?

Tags: sourcegraph

I want to do a Sourcegraph search and have it show only results from files with a certain extension.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `file:` token to filter results by filename regex. For example, [`file:\.go$` would limit results to files ending in ".go"](https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=repo:%5Egithub%5C.com/kubernetes/kubernetes%24+file:%5C.go%24).

The full search query syntax is documented here: https://docs.sourcegraph.com/code_search/reference/queries

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to search `drizzle` migration commands in `bash` script that ends in `.sh` extension so I used:

```bash
drizzle file:\.sh$
```

`\` is used to escape the `.` while `$` signifies the end of the string. So `.sh` is surrounded by `\` & `$`.

Works for other languages as well:

1. `\.js$` - JavaScript
2. `\.ts$` - TypeScript
3. `\.jsx$` or `\.tsx` - JSX
4. `\.py$` - Python